# How to correctly set the date and time in a bluetooth low energy peripheral?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a sensor device and a corresponding iOS-app that shall communicate using Bluetooth low energy. The sensor device needs to maintain the current date and time in a real-time clock. Now, I am confused as to what would be the correct way to set the time and date in the sensor device if I want to implement the Bluetooth standard services as much as possible because the official documentation is contradictory:

- in the [ServiceViewer](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.current_time.xml) for the "Current Time Service", it says that the "current time" characteristic can optionally be written to. This would mean that the GATT client (i.e., the smartphone) can simply set the sensor's time by writing to this characteristic.
- in the [detailed specifications](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/CTS.aspx) regarding that service however, it says that writing to that characteristic is forbidden.

The information in the Service Viewer is much more recent (2014) compared to the detailed specs (2011), so is it safe to assume that the detailed specs just have not been updated?

Despite extensive online research I could not find any example of somebody settings the current date and time in a BT-LE sensor.

Any clue as to what the best way to proceed would be?

Comment: You are going to have to write an app to talk to the device anyway, so it doesn't matter which method you use; you can either update the current time service attribute or define your own attribute.

Comment: As far as I know iOS natively supports current time characteristics server implementation. So if in your sensor device if you implement the current time characteristics client then you will receive the time updates per minute (provided your device is bonded)

Comment: In Current Time Service Spec v1.0 write to date-time characteristic is not allowed. A later revision V1.1 specifies the write support as optional.

Answer (score 3):

I have implement this and it will work my side,

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
var comp = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute, .second, .weekday, .nanosecond], from: date)
let milisecond = comp.nanosecond!/1000000
let quiterValue = milisecond/256
let year_mso = comp.year! & 0xFF
let year_lso = (comp.year! >> 8) & 0xFF
let ajjust_reason = 1

let timeZone = calendar.component(.timeZone, from: date)
let DSTZoon = Calendar.current.timeZone.isDaylightSavingTime()

let Year_MSO_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(year_mso))
let Year_LSO_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(year_lso))
let MONTH_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.month!))
let DAY_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.day!))
let HOUR_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.hour!))
let MINUTE_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.minute!))
let SECOND_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.second!))
let WEEKDAY_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.weekday!))
let QUITERVALUE_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(quiterValue))
let AJRSON_Unsinged = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(ajjust_reason))

//Current Time Write on tag

let currentTimeArray = [Year_MSO_BYTE, Year_LSO_BYTE, MONTH_BYTE, DAY_BYTE ,HOUR_BYTE ,MINUTE_BYTE ,SECOND_BYTE , WEEKDAY_BYTE , QUITERVALUE_BYTE , AJRSON_BYTE];
let currentTimeArray_data = NSData(bytes: currentTimeArray, length: currentTimeArray.length)
if Device.Current_Time != nil {
       deviceValue.peripheral.writeValue(currentTimeArray_data as Data, for:    GrillRightDevice.Current_Time!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start The time service in iOS Phone.
Read the Time from Phone (exposed by service) into sensor. ( for this your iPHone acts as peripheral )
Sensor in this case acts as a Master.
Get the data from iPhone and set it into sensor.
I hope you can code for  Sensor.

Answer (score 0):

The Current Time Service is intended to be a provider of the current time; clients would use it to obtain the time. Hence, having a client write to it does not really make sense. If your device does not have a Real Time Clock then it cannot provide a time service. If your device needs the time and does not have an RTC then your device must become a client to another device which can provide it.

Comment: As @HarryQ noted above, in https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.current_time.xml Write is an option.