# Android BLE - write timestamp onto Health Thermometer

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im developing an Android app to read temperature from Health Thermometer with Bluetooth Low Energy. Able to connect and parse the Temperature Measurement characteristic `(0x2A1C)` and retrieving temperature value and timestamp.

Now my requirement is if timestamp onto the device is old value ignore the reading and write current timestamp. When a next reading is taken the timestamp has to match to a nearby value.

On which characteristic can I write this timestamp value?

After successful discovery, GATT server gives 6 services (mentioning below only important characteristics)

1) Generic Access (UUID:0x1800)
   Characteristics:  a) Device Name (UUID:0x2A00) - properties: `READ, WRITE`

2) Generic Attribute (UUID: 0x1801)
   Characteristics: a) Service Changed (UUID: 0x2A05) - properties: `INDICATE`
   Descriptor: Client characteristic configuration (UUID:0x2902) - properties: `INDICATE`

3) Health Thermometer (UUID:1809)
   Characteristics: a) Temperature Measurement (UUID: 0x2A1C) - properties: `INDICATE`
   Descriptor: Client characteristic configuration (UUID:0x2902)

4) Battery service

5) Device information

6) Nordic LED Button Service (UUID: 00001523-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123)
   Characteristics: a) Button (UUID: 00001524-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123) - properties: `INDICATE, NOTIFY, WRITE`

Can anyone help me out on which characteristic to write?
If so, how? Is there any other way?

Comment: Which thermometer do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Write onto the last characteristic 00001524-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123

On the characteristic setWriteType WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT then on all of its Descriptors ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE.

You will get the result in onCharacteristicChanged callback.

Create commandlist of byte array of size 8.

Include time-stamp in this along with other commands. Set this value on characteristic and write to GATT server.

Comment: That is a clever solution. However, I wonder why the health thermometer has no time service (like Current Time Service) so that one has to manipulate the button service instead.

Comment: @Nebr That could have been more easier for read/write operations if such service is included. May be answer by VERTICON in this post justifies why it is not being included http://stackoverflow.com/a/38745382/7494831

Comment: I didn't know that about CTS yet, but okay, writing the time via CTS would indeed be a misuse of this service as well. (However, I still think some sort of time service should have been included in the thermometer if it uses time stamps.)